# Vue - The Cli gives an error on installing

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I just installed Ubuntu and tried to install the vue cli but got this error

here's the error

```js
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/m/.npm/_logs/2022-08-17T06_58_04_490Z-debug.log
```

I tried installing other npm packages and it worked, the cli is the only one that doesn't work

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: You haven't shared how you tried to install that package, neither what you've tried to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it has to do with the user rights. [Here's an article](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) on npm addressing your problem.

Boils down to two things you can try:

- Reinstall npm with a node version manager
- Manually change npm's default directory

I had this issue many times in the past and tried various solutions. Some of them didn't do much more than f*cking my setup even more, that's why it's really worthy to follow the official path.

Comment: How can I change npm's version using nvm?
EDIT: nvm figured it out